# How to show sum of a column at the table footer for each page in SSRS 2005?

Tags: reporting-services

I've a SSRS report consisting of a table control. Table has three columns (X, Y, Z) and is populating with data from a database stored procedure. In table footer, I'm displaying sum of column Z using formula `=Sum(Fields!Z.Value)`. The table footer is shown only on last page not on each page. Now I've to show sum of column Z page wise. i.e. if report is consisting of 4 pages and each page except the last has 25 rows and last page has 20 page, then I've to show sum of column Z for page 1 at the table footer, sum of column Z for page 2 at the table footer and so on ...

I can show table footer on each page but unable to calculate sum of column Z for each page.

Can any one help me in this regards?

Comment: Samir, can you explain you question more clearly? Do you need to show sum of Z only at last page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your footer only on last page, you should set the visibility of footer's textBox in proper way.

**1.** Add TextBox to footer.
**2.** TextBox Properties -> Visibility -> Show or hide based on expression:

```
=IIF(Globals!PageNumber = Globals!TotalPages, False, True)
```

**3.** In TextBox's Expression write:

```
=Sum(Fields!Z.Value, "YourDataSet")
```